# ¿List o ArrayList en Java?

Tags: java

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre las siguientes implementaciones?

```
ArrayList<String> xxx = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> zzz      = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**List** es una colección, y una colección puede ser interfaces y clase abstracta que nos permite identificar los objetos independientemente de la implementación. Es decir, son genéricas.

Mientras, un **ArrayList** es contenedor que contiene una implementación de la colección List.

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo de las colecciones y sus relaciones en Java: https://en.proft.me/2013/11/3/java-collection-framework-cheat-sheet/

En base a esto, ***List*** es una interfaz genérica que representa una colección ordenada de elementos que pueden repetirse.

Mientras, dos listas de propósito general serían las clases ***LinkedList*** y ***ArrayList*** y de propósito específico, ***Vector*** y ***CopyOnWriteArrayList***.

En tu duda, la ***ArrayList*** es un array que se maneja como una clase y no tiene tamaño fijo. Es eficiente cuando se realizan muchos acceso y en este caso los elementos se añaden al final. Permite que se puedan eliminar elementos intermedios, pero eso provocará un desplazamiento de índices.

En cambio, para una clase ***LinkedList*** tendremos una lista enlazada en la que los elementos se añaden en cualquier parte de la lista muy fácilmente. Aquí, para encontrar un elemento hay que recorrer la lista. Es eficiente cuando el tamaño fluctúa y sobre todo en posiciones centrales.

¿Qué sucede si utilizas ***List*** como lo haces en tu caso?, que podrías cambiar el tipo de *zzz* a ***LinkedList*** en su definición y todo sería compatible 100% y fácilmente. No obstante, en el primer caso de *xxx* tendrías que cambiar en todos los sitios el tipo debido a que estas implementando un ***ArrayList*** y podrías tener problemas si lo cambias a ***LinkedLIst***. Por eso se recomienda el uso de ***List***, como lo haces de *zzz*.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void insert(List<Dato> datos) {
  for(Dato dato:datos){
    db.executeUpdate("insert into datos(desc,cantidad) values(:desc,:cantidad)",
    new Object[]{dato.getDescripcion(),dato.getCantidad()});
  }
}


public static void insert(Dato[] datos) {
  for(Dato dato:datos){
    db.executeUpdate("insert into datos(desc,cantidad) values(:desc,:cantidad)",
    new Object[]{dato.getDescripcion(),dato.getCantidad()});
  }
}
```

Como puedes ver, es prácticamente lo mismo, la diferencia es que al invocar el primer método puedes pasar como párametro un ArrayList, LinkedList, Vector o tu propia clase que implemente la interfaz List

un enlace que te puede ayudar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716597/array-or-list-in-java-which-is-faster

Answer (score 0):

**List** es una interface mientras que **ArrayList** es una de las tantas implementaciones de la interface List (a su vez List extiende de la interface **Collection**).

A priori, entonces, no hay diferencia, polimórficamente vas a estar trabajando con un ArrayList. Pero me parece mas correcto usar la segunda sentencia y trabajar contra la interface y nunca contra el tipo concreto. De esta manera tenes la flexibilidad de instanciar otra implementación diferente de la interface List (LinkedList por ejemplo) y tu código va a seguir funcionando igual, gracias a que los contratos se mantienen.

Answer (score 0):

La diferencia radica en las buenas practicas a nivel de codigo, en este caso especifico el desacoplamiento de las implementaciones. En el primer caso, al estar instanceando una clase especifica, es decir, una implementacion especifica: `ArrayList<String> xxx`, estas obligado a suministrar un `ArrayList<String>`, es decir, tu codigo esta acoplado a una implementacion especifica. En el segundo caso, al estar 'instanceando' un objeto de la abstraccion, puedes suministrar cualquier implementacion de esta abstraccion. Ejemplos: `List<String> xxx = new ArrayList<>();`  o  `List<String> xxx = new LinkedList<>()`, o `List<String> xxx = new Vector<>();`.

Comment: *al estar 'instanceando' un objeto de la abstraccion* -> me temo que la instanciación es igual en ambos casos, lo que difiere es la declaración. En cuanto a la instancia, siempre es un `ArrayList`, puesto que se instancia con la palabra reservada `new`, no al declarar el tipo de la variable.